# Python iCalendar Attendee format

Tags: python, parsing, icalendar

In trying to parse and .ics file using iCalendar pyton lib I've run into an issue when there are multiple attendees to a meeting. When there are multiple attendees the .get function returns a list of vCalAddress attendees. Is there a way to further parse out the attendees or to return just on item in this list?

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event, vDDDTypes, vCalAddress
g = open('Example.ics','rb')
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())

for event in gcal.walk('vevent'):
    org = event.get('organizer')
    date = event.get('dtstart')
    summary = event.get('summary')
    atten = event.get('attendee')

    print (date.dt)
    print (summary)
    print (org)
    print (atten)
    print ('-----------')
```

Output

```
2017-09-29 15:00:00-07:00
FC08F10 Review
mailto:Example1@gmail.com
[vCalAddress('mailto:Example2@gmail.com'), 
vCalAddress('mailto:Example3@gmail.com'), 
vCalAddress('mailto:Example4@gmail.com')]
-----------
```

**EDIT**
I attempted to use the get_line function for the attendees field and through the error messages I received I figured out that vCalAddress is a python list. I edited my print statement to the following `print(atten[0])` and for the most part I get what I'm looking for (which is the first result of the attendees list). The one draw back to this at the moment though is that if there is only one attendee you just get the first letter of that attendee's output (if you simply use `print(atten[0])` if you use `print(atten)` with one attendee you get the whole string. I'll keep digging on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get specific attendees when there is more then one you can do the following

```
atten = event.get('attendee')
print(atten[0])
print(atten[1])
```

If there is just one attendee there is no need to use the list index just print the variable

```
print(atten)
```

**EDIT**

To Parse out multiple attendees do the following:

```
for event in gcal.walk('vevent'):
  if atten[i] == 'm':
        print(atten)
    else: 
        print(atten[i])
        ++i
```

Where 'm' is the first letter of the attendee string. The first letter of you attendee will depend on how its formatted in your .ics file. all my contacts being with 'mailto:'

Comment: Okay but how do you figure out when there is only one or mulitple attendee's?